# Do these two characters in a silver inlay on a small tray have a special meaning? (Characters identified: 大吉)

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology, character-identification

[image]

An inlaid silver tray with what is possibly a Buddhist symbol

Comment: The word 大吉 (good luck) is embedded in the graphic

Comment: Yes, and as for the graphics, 大吉 is embedded in a bottle gourd which ordinarily is used as a vessel for containing water or wine, or in Taoist mythology for containing or capturing malevolent spirits. In this case, however, it is used to "suck in" and "capture"  "Good Luck" which all those wriggly lines represent. So it is Taoist not Buddhist.

Comment: I thought about 吉 too. It's just that the top part of 吉 is 士, not 土.